Graphical problem with double y axis
Initially, I displayed all my data with a single y axis (without concern for scale for the quantities a0, a1 and a2 which go from 0 to 1).
I would like, for these 3 quantities, to display them on a second y axis on the right: the problem is that the display does not correspond at all when I go with 2 y axes and I don't understand why
The initial code :
\documentclass[border=0.2cm,11pt,convert={ghostscript,outext=.png,density=800x800}]{standalone}%conversion en png avec ghostscript

%COMPILé AVEC XeLaTeX

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}            % Permet l'affichage de deux axes y
\usepackage{siunitx}% unités et écriture de valeurs
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    
\footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
    xmin=0,xmax=25,
    ymin=0,ymax=14,
    xlabel=volume versé (mL),
    ylabel=pH,
    ytick distance=2,
    minor y tick num=1,
    minor x tick num=4,
    grid,
    grid=both,% grilles primaire et secondaire
    title=titrage pH-métrique d'un acide faible,
    axis line shift=3pt,
    xtick align=outside,
    ytick align=outside,
    tickpos=left,
    legend pos=north west,
    ]
    % courbe calculée :
    \addplot [thick,NavyBlue]
     table [x=V,y=pH,col sep=semicolon]
    {donnees_fumarique.csv};
    \addlegendentry{pH}

    % tracé concentration AH2 :
    \addplot [densely dashed,red,
            yscale=12 % 
            ]
    table [x=V,y=a0,col sep=semicolon]
    {donnees_fumarique.csv};
    \addlegendentry{\ce{AH2}}
    
    % tracé concentration acide :
    \addplot [densely dotted,OliveGreen,thick,yscale=12,
    ]
    table [x=V,y=a1,col sep=semicolon]
    {donnees_fumarique.csv};
    \addlegendentry{\ce{HA^-}}
    
    % tracé concentration A2- :
\addplot [densely dotted,purple,thick,yscale=12,
]
table [x=V,y=a2,col sep=semicolon]
{donnees_fumarique.csv};
\addlegendentry{\ce{A^2-}}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The code I'm trying for the 2 axes :
\documentclass[border=0.2cm,11pt,convert={ghostscript,outext=.png,density=800x800}]{standalone}%conversion en png avec ghostscript

%COMPILé AVEC XeLaTeX

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}            % Permet l'affichage de deux axes y
\usepackage{siunitx}% unités et écriture de valeurs
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    
\footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
    xmin=0,xmax=25,
    ymin=0,ymax=14,
    xlabel=volume versé (mL),
    ylabel=pH,
    ytick distance=2,
    minor y tick num=1,
    minor x tick num=4,
    grid,
    grid=both,% grilles primaire et secondaire
    title=titrage pH-métrique d'un acide faible,
    axis line shift=3pt,
    xtick align=outside,
    ytick align=outside,
    tickpos=left,
    legend pos=north west,
    ]
    % courbe calculée :
    \addplot [thick,NavyBlue]
     table [x=V,y=pH,col sep=semicolon]
    {donnees_fumarique.csv};
    \addlegendentry{pH}
    \end{axis}
    
    \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
    ymin=0,ymax=120,
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line = none,
    ytick align=outside,
    yticl=right,
    legend pos=north west,
    ]
    
    % tracé concentration AH2 :
    \addplot [densely dashed,red,
            yscale=100 % 
            ]
    table [x=V,y=a0,col sep=semicolon]
    {donnees_fumarique.csv};
    \addlegendentry{\ce{AH2}}
    
    % tracé concentration acide :
    \addplot [densely dotted,OliveGreen,thick,yscale=100,
    ]
    table [x=V,y=a1,col sep=semicolon]
    {donnees_fumarique.csv};
    \addlegendentry{\ce{HA^-}}
    
    % tracé concentration A2- :
\addplot [densely dotted,purple,thick,yscale=100,
]
table [x=V,y=a2,col sep=semicolon]
{donnees_fumarique.csv};
\addlegendentry{\ce{A^2-}}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The data :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/106SCvB_KQE9uZdy66H2a7OpulVESyjsP/view?usp=sharing

Sorry, what do you mean by „ the display does not correspond at all“?

@MS-SPO in the 1st figure, we see that the red dotted curve decreases from 0 mL while in the 2nd figure this is only the case from 12 mL: the graphic representation is therefore not at all the same

Thank you. Assuming the data files are identical, to me it looks like in some cases you didn’t specify xmin and xmax, did you?

the data file is the same. Indeed, I did not specify xmin and xmax for the 2nd y axis

Hm, still not sure, what your problem is. However, with some minor changes your 2nd code results in:

Some minor changes:

disable ghostscript and fontenc
2nd \begin{axis}: assign same range  xmin=0,xmax=25,
dto.: this way there is no grid-mismatch between left and right scales    ymin=0,ymax=140,
moving 2nd legend to make it visible AND assignment of left/right scales more evident


%\documentclass[border=0.2cm,11pt,convert={ghostscript,outext=.png,density=800x800}]{standalone}%conversion en png avec ghostscript
%
%%COMPILé AVEC XeLaTeX
%
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}            % Permet l'affichage de deux axes y
\usepackage{siunitx}% unités et écriture de valeurs
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    
%\footnotesize
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
    xmin=0,xmax=25,
    ymin=0,ymax=14,
    xlabel=volume versé (mL),
    ylabel=pH,
    ytick distance=2,
    minor y tick num=1,
    minor x tick num=4,
    grid,
    grid=both,% grilles primaire et secondaire
    title=titrage pH-métrique d'un acide faible,
    axis line shift=3pt,
    xtick align=outside,
    ytick align=outside,
    tickpos=left,
    legend pos=north west,
    ]
    % courbe calculée :
    \addplot [thick,NavyBlue]
            table [x=V,y=pH,col sep=semicolon]
            {donnees_fumarique.csv};
    \addlegendentry{pH}
  \end{axis}
    
  \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
    ymin=0,ymax=140,        % <<<<<<<<
    xmin=0,xmax=25,         % <<<<<<<<
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line = none,
    ytick align=outside,
%    yticl=right,
    legend pos=south east,  % <<<<<<<<
    ]
    
    % tracé concentration AH2 :
    \addplot [densely dashed,red,
              yscale=100 % 
              ]
            table [x=V,y=a0,col sep=semicolon]
            {donnees_fumarique.csv};
    \addlegendentry{\ce{AH2}}
    
    % tracé concentration acide :
    \addplot [densely dotted,OliveGreen,thick,yscale=100,
            ]
            table [x=V,y=a1,col sep=semicolon]
            {donnees_fumarique.csv};
    \addlegendentry{\ce{HA^-}}
    
    % tracé concentration A2- :
    \addplot [densely dotted,purple,thick,yscale=100,
            ]
            table [x=V,y=a2,col sep=semicolon]
            {donnees_fumarique.csv};
            \addlegendentry{\ce{A^2-}}
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

P.S.: Perhaps the ylabel for the right y axis should be [a.u.] (arbitrary units)?

thanks for your return. The unit is the percentage of the second y axis
